# upgrading maven-core-2.0.9.jar to maven-core-3.8.4.jar while building java application using maven to fix Black Duck vulnerability

Tags: java, maven, security, jar, pom.xml

We are building our Kafka streaming application written in java using maven.
It is observed that while building application maven-core-2.0.9.jar is downloaded.

We are using **Black Duck** to analyze libraries for security vulnerabilities and maven-core-2.0.9.jar is marked as high vulnerable jar. Black Duck is suggesting us to upgrade this jar to higher version maven-core-3.8.4.jar. How do I do this as this is not part of dependency tree of the application.

Below is the pom.xml that we are using. Do I have to do any changes so that we use latest version of maven/maven libraries/ plugins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sampleproject.</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <jackson.version>2.10.1</jackson.version>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            **/*.xml,
            **/*.properties,
            build.properties,
            package/**,
            config/**
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <!-- Dependancies of project --> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.dell.sadatahub.azure.SACCollectionProcessorTopology</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <dependencyConvergence />
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>libs-release-local</name>
            <url>https://dcsartifacts.dell.com/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot-local</name>
            <url>https://dcsartifacts.dell.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: First you can't update a dependency of use tool/library ...that must be done by the library/tool maintainers... Apart from that I'm not really astonished about that because maven-core-2.0.9 is of 2008!...

Comment: Hi Khamarbaise, Thank you for your response. I have updated pom.xml that we are using. Can you check if we modify pom.xml latest libraries will be used? maven-core-.2.0.0.jar has security vulnerability so we want to use latest library

Comment: I can only see that you are using maven plugins (as usual). I would use version 3.0.0 of maven-enforce-plugin and maybe a most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.8.1 https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)...I'm not sure if your scanner does only scan the dependencies of your application?

Comment: HI Khmarbaise, Thanks again for your response. I upgraded all plugins to latest version but still maven-core-2.0.9.jar is used for building !!

Comment: Have you specified all plugins you are using because in the post there are only a limited number. For example maven-resources-plugin, maven-install-plugin is missing?

Comment: Yes I have mentioned all plugins. Only missing in the POM which I have pasted are dependencies used in project